# Using regex to filter year of fixed length 0 or 4 digit

Tags: php, javascript, regex

i want to filter year using regex in php or javascript.

which contain only number and its length is 0(if not input) or 4 if(insert)
it is not accept 1, 2 or 3 length for ex 123.

i know regex for 0 to 4 digit which is `^[0-9]{0,4}$` or `^\d{0,4}$`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the following:

```
^([0-9]{4})?$
```

`^` - start of line

`([0-9]{4})?` - four numbers, optionally (because of the `?`)

`$` - end of line

Comment: but i don't allow user to  1,2 or 3 digit number insert only 4 digit if insert or 0 if leave it blank.

Comment: Yes, this is what this regular expression is matching. Either 0 numbers (which is ^$) or four numbers which is ^[0-9]{4}$ , in regular expressions ? means 'the thing that preceded me is 'optional'.

Comment: thanks i cant give +1 to this ans because i have not enough reputation but i give you +1. thanks

Comment: @Piyush that's ok, I already capped my daily reputation limit before I answered your question anyway, I'm just glad it helped :)

Answer (score 3):

I know this question has already been answered but just to be more clear and as an alternate solution i would come up with this:

In your pattern:

```
^[0-9]{0,4}$
```

`{0,4}` will allow to match numbers of length 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4. To eliminate length 1, 2 and 3 you can also use something like:

```
^\d{4}?$
```

Here:

```
^    = beginning of line
\d   = any digit - equivalent of [0-9]
{4}  = exactly four times
?    = makes the preceding item optional
$    = end of line
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

You do not need to use regular expressions for something as simple as matching a year:

```
if (ctype_digit($year) && strlen($year) === 4) {
    echo 'This is a year';
} else {
    echo 'Not a year';
}
```

Comment: Regardless, it's useful to be able to use regex. E.g. in a framework, where a year is just one of the many types of variables with many different patterns, but all use the same validation function.