# Regex to match a pattern or empty value

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need to match a pattern where i can have an alphanumeric value of size 4 or an empty value. 
My current Regex

```
"[0-9a-z]{0|4}");
```

does not works for empty values.

I have tried the following two patterns but none of them works for me:

```
"(?:[0-9a-z]{4} )?");
"[0-9a-z]{0|4}");
```

I use http://xenon.stanford.edu/~xusch/regexp/ to validate my Regex but sometimes i get stuck for RegEx. Is there a way/tools that i can use to ensure i have to come here for very complex issues.

Examples i may want to match: we12, 3444, de1q, {empty}
But not want to match : @$12, #12q, 1, qwe, qqqqq

No UpperCase is matching.

Comment: Can you show an example of what it is that you want to match?

Comment: Uppercase letters should be allowed?

Comment: @donfuxx no. but if i have to do i simply use A-Z/a-z|0-9 as set of chars ?

Comment: read this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15723663/using-regex-to-filter-year-of-fixed-length-0-or-4-digit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Overall you could use the pattern `expression|$`, so it will try to match the `expression` or (`|`) the empty , and we make sure we don't have anything after that including the anchor `$`. 
Furthermore, we could enclose it with a capture group `(...)`, so it will finally look like this:

```regex
ˆ(expresison|)$
```

So applying it to your need, it would end up to be like:

```
^([0-9a-z]{4}|)$
```

[here](http://regex101.com/r/bI5aB8) is an example

**EDIT:**

If you want to match also uppercases, add `A-Z` to the pattern:

```
^([0-9a-zA-Z]{4}|)$
```

Comment: +1 Did you read my mind? Was about to write exactly the same regex, incl. posting same demo link :-P

Comment: `Warning: An empty alternative effectively makes this group optional which suggests the alternative is completely redundant` 
The solution was posted by other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15723663/using-regex-to-filter-year-of-fixed-length-0-or-4-digit `^([0-9a-zA-Z]{4})?$` **DOWNVOTE!**

Comment: Yes, thats what i want.. either an empty value or a value of 4 chars long.

Comment: Why would you prefer using `ˆ(expr|)$` over `ˆ(expr)?$`

Comment: Just to be suggestive. In fact both are absolutely the same, and i've never found in any source it is a "bad practice" (or that it is slower and we should avoid using it). So to keep the same rational from the questioner, I opted using it this way.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose "empty value" means empty line in the question above. If that's the case you can use this expression:

```
^\s*$|[a-z0-9]{4}
```

which will match alphanumeric patterns of size 4 or empty lines as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012788/how-to-check-if-a-line-is-blank-using-regex)